# How long does at(1) wait for a scheduled task to complete?

Tags: cron, anacron

Say one scheduled a task with

```
at 11pm on Friday
> long-running-command
Ctrl-D
```

How long can the long-running command run? Will the `at` daemon force termination after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`at` simply runs the command at the specified time.  It does not influence the command at that time or afterwards.  Whether a process continues to run is decided by the kernel, (in particular the memory manager can kill it if it's consuming too many resources), and other subsystems you or your distribution may have installed to ensure system stability.

Aside from that, the issue listed in [the manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/at.1p.html) may have an influence on how it is run:

> As `at` is currently implemented as a setuid program, other environment 
>       variables (e.g., LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD) are also not  exported.

But this will only have an effect on how it runs, not directly on how long it runs for.

So, to answer the question directly, it will run **as long as the system lets it run** which is usually **forever** so long as it **behaves** and doesn't choose to terminate itself.